# Forgot to provide details of children on an Indian railways booking

Tags: trains, tickets, bookings, indian-railways, age-limits

IRCTC (The Indian Railway online ticket booking agency) provides an option to specify details of children under five years of age who are travelling with the ticketed passengers.

While booking a ticket through IRCTC, I have forgotten to fill in the personal information of my children (both under 5) in the form. One child is 3 years and another is 4.5 years old. Will they be allowed to travel with me or can it lead to a problem during boarding/journey?

Comment: Pranjal, do children travel for free?  How could you book tickets for them if you didn't fill out their details? Please edit your question and explain this so that it can remain open.

Comment: @davidricherby Uhm , never mind. This question is confusing, voted to close. Thanks.

Comment: Children under 5 do not need a ticket while travelling with Indian Railways so I guess it is OK even if you don't fill their names in the form.

Comment: @JonathanReez Technically the other question is the dup of this one as this question is older. But as this is closed, the other (newer) question is getting the answers.